# What's that something Tuddy is offering?

Tags: plot-explanation, goodfellas

Guest at the marriage party, handover envelopes as gifts to
Karen, newly wedded wife.

> TUDDY'S WIFE: So beautiful. I want to cry.
>
> TUDDY: Here is **something** to help you get started.

[image]

It's unclear to me what's that something. What's that something Tuddy is offering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's cash. A common tradition for such weddings at the time.

> Weddings are expensive, especially Italian weddings where the guest list can easily climb into the many hundreds; and putting together an acceptable reception to feed and entertain hundreds of guests can easily become costly. So what couple wouldn't like to start their life together with a little extra padding in the bank? **It is even custom in Italian weddings to give money as a gift to the bride and groom, so much so that the bride carries a special satin purse specifically for money gifted to her by the guests. Called la borsa and usually held onto during the reception by an older family member, the little satin purse is where guests can place envelopes of money for the couple**, or even money to reserve a dance with the beaming bride.
>
> [Source](https://www.italcultur.org.uk/gift_giving.html)

Answer (score 2):

### The envelope contains money

> WE SEE VARIO approach and hand KAREN an envelope.
>
> VARIO: Here.  This is for you.
>
> KAREN: (looking down at the envelope) Paulie, you shouldn't.
>
> WE SEE that VARIO's envelope is richly embossed with hearts and
> flowers and has a clear window in front through which she can see
> several neatly-folded hundred, dollar bills.
>
> When KAREN looks up, she sees that EVERY WISEGUY and his WIFE are
> lined up before her and that they are ALL holding envelopes with clear
> windows in front.
>
> CUT TO:
>
> KAREN perspiring a little as she accepts and thanks the DOZENS OF
> WISEGUYS giving her the envelopes. WE ALSO SEE HENRY has opened a
> plastic supermarket shopping bag under the table where he is stuffing
> the envelopes just as soon as KAREN accepts them.
>
> <sub><sup>[Good Fellas: Script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/goodfellas.html)</sup></sub>